# Support mobile navigation on all devices and browsers: but what's its name?

Tags: html, css, browser, navigation, compatibility

I'm using the following code for a navigation on mobile devices. (Code very truncated.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html    {
    background-color:rgba(190, 234, 16, 0.30);
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}
nav {
    text-align:center;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:30px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ .navigation {
    display:none;
}
#checkbox_label {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<label id="checkbox_label" for="checkbox">Navigation</label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">

<nav class="navigation">
<p><a href="">Test1</a></p>
<p><a href="">Test2</a></p>
<p><a href="">Test3</a></p>
<p><a href="">Test4</a></p>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

By tapping on "Navigation" you can show and hide the navigation. that works fantastic. I also checked it with several devices and browsers, but of course not all.

Naturally I want this to work for every user of my website, full browser compatibility. I also tried to google the browser support but it's not easy because I don't even know what's the name of this "functionality".

Does anybody of you know something about this? Name of this "functionality"? Browser compatibility?

Answer (score -1):

I think its Mobile navigation menu !!